# JavaScript -- in-line switch statement?

Tags: javascript

if I want to check that the same value is equal to multiple different values with a different result each time, like so (for example):

```
var someArray = new (
    max - min < 128 ? Int8Array : 
    max - min < 256 ? Uint8Array :
    max - min < 32768 ? Int16Array : 
    max - min < 65536 ? Uint16Array :
    max - min < 2147483648 ? Int32Array :
    max - min < 4294967296 ? Uint32Array :
    Array
)
```

I need to rewrite the value each time (max - min), or even if it was a single variable, that would still be repetitive. Is there any way to simply write the value once but get the same result, like:

```
var someArray = new (
        inlineSwitch(max - min) $$ //just an example symbol
        < 128 ? Int8Array : 
        < 256 ? Uint8Array :
        < 32768 ? Int16Array : 
        < 65536 ? Uint16Array :
        < 2147483648 ? Int32Array :
        < 4294967296 ? Uint32Array
)
```

or something? Is there any kind of way to do something like this? Or can a function be made that takes some kind of similar input to this?

EDIT

I added the last "Array" condition at the end, if its greater than any of those, that should also be taken into consideration. Also speed is the main thing -- if this is part of a function, than making many additional variables could slow things down.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an object instead, indexed by the number, whose value is the associated constructor, and then `.find` the appropriate entry:

```
const constructorByNumRange = {
  128 : Int8Array,
  256: Uint8Array,
  // ...
};

const diff = max - min;
const constructorEntry = Object.entries(constructorByNumRange)
  .find(([numStr]) => Number(numStr) < diff);
const someArray = new constructorEntry[1]();
```

If there's a chance that there's no found entry, then you can add a check that the `.find` returns an entry:

```
if (!constructorEntry) {
  // handle situation in which the diff range was not found
  throw new Error('Not found');
}
```

You could also use an array of arrays instead of an object:

```
const constructorByNumRange = [
  [128, Int8Array],
  [256, Uint8Array],
  // ...
};

const diff = max - min;
const constructorEntry = constructorByNumRange
  .find(([num]) => num < diff);
```

Comment: what if `find` returns `undefined`? it's sort of hard to tell if that's even possible in this program.

Comment: `[ [ 128, Int8Array ], [ 256, ... ], ... ]` seems like it would be a better structure. The "keys" don't get converted to strings and arrays are explicitly ordered.

Comment: Numeric keys always get iterated over in sequential order, thankfully, but yeah, the current `Number` casting feels a bit ugly. I thought about a Map but an array of arrays sounds better

Answer (score 0):

#### I am using an object array to keep comparable items, then using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter , [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) - to compare the diff, then sending to a func to obtain the result using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```
const numberTypesList = [
  { 128: Int8Array },
  {
    256: Uint8Array
  },
  { 32768: Int16Array },
  { 65536: Uint16Array },
  { 2147483648: Int32Array },
  { 4294967296: Uint32Array }
];

const min = 10,
  max = 340;

const diff = max - min;

const getNumberTypeFn = input => {
  if (typeof input === "object") {
    return Object.values(input)[0];
  } else {
    //return empty function or anything you want to
    return () => {};
  }
};
const numberTypefn = numberTypesList.find(x => Object.keys(x)[0] < diff);
console.log(getNumberTypeFn(numberTypefn));
```

https://r4jx15jz34.codesandbox.io/